# Register form for CB Login not giving status report after registering

Tags: community-builder

For registering, implemented CB Login module ([tnssecurities.in](http://www.tnssecurities.in/)). After filling Register form, getting no message if registration successful/not successful. Backend, under Registration menu of Community Builder component, opted Yes for Email Confirmation and No for Admin Approval. When successful (verified from User Management list), there is no message of successful registration in the user's email. Need help regarding how to edit settings such that users get a message of successful registration.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly there should be 2 things to check when using CB for your registration.

1. verify that the allow registration setting in CB is set to disregard the COM_USERS setting. This allows users to register and the COM_USERS methods to fire even if Joomla user registration is turned off.
2. look at the users plugin and verify that the setting to not send registration emails is not turned on. This will disable user emails going out if it is not configured correctly.

Comment: @BagraRajeev if this answer resolved your issue please be sure to mark it as accepted.